# How is the ACL set on USB-devices?

Tags: usb, debian, permissions

I'm new to acl's so this is blackmagic to me. But what I have is a camera that I want to talk to.

So I got a netbooted debian machine:

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.10 (squeeze)
Release:    6.0.10
Codename:   squeeze
```

To that machine a I got a camera attached:

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsusb | grep Nikon
Bus 001 Device 092: ID 04b0:0428 Nikon Corp. 
ulf@term13:~(0)$ ls -alF /dev/bus/usb/001/092 
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root root 189, 91 25 sep 10.05 /dev/bus/usb/001/092
```

Note the `+` at the end of the permissionstring `crw-rw-r--+`. That indicates that there is an [ACL](https://wiki.debian.org/Permissions#Access_Control_Lists_in_Linux) in work here:

```
ulf@term13:~(1)$ getfacl /dev/bus/usb/001/092 
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/001/092
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
user:knut:rw-
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

Apparently the user knut has additional `rw` permissions here. **But how did he get them?**

I can set the same permissions to my user with `setfacl`. But whatever set like that will not be present after the camera has been reconnected. After toggling the camera on and off ones it actually gets *mounted* on another device:

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsusb | grep Nikon
Bus 001 Device 093: ID 04b0:0428 Nikon Corp.
```

But the permissions for the new 093-device is the same as old 092 (without any extra permissions I added to the 092).

There is an `udev`-rule-file that should be the one in charge I think, but its empty ???

```
ulf@term13:~(0)$ ls -alF /etc/udev/rules.d/90-libgphoto2.rules 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 26 aug  2014 /etc/udev/rules.d/90-libgphoto2.rules
```

And non of the other udev-files has any stuff related to this.

Is there some file where this is configured? This is setup by a sysadmin that is not present here any more so I need to fix it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Apparently the user knut has additional rw permissions here. But how did he get them?

**Is the user "knut" logged in at the console?** On many recent Linux systems, *udev* grants device access based on who is currently logged on.

(Here "console" means the main display+keyboard [attached directly to the computer](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/C/console.html) – whether it's text-mode or graphical has no relevance.)

Older versions (including Debian 6) have rules with `TAGS+="udev-acl"` and obtain the session status from ConsoleKit if present, pam_console otherwise. Check `who`, the contents of `/var/run/console`, and perhaps `ck-list-sessions`. These mechanisms are relatively simple – if the user is logged in to the "console", they get access, otherwise not.

Distributions using systemd take the same information from *systemd-logind* and use the `"uaccess"` tag instead. In addition to the console, logind additionally supports "multi-seat" systems, where multiple users can work on multiple displays at once, with each having an assigned USB port.

If you want to bypass this and grant access to other users, you can use traditional "group" permissions for this – write an udev rule assigning your device to `GROUP="camera-users"` and add people to that group.

> After toggling the camera on and off ones it actually gets mounted on another device:
>
> ```
> ulf@term13:~(0)$ lsusb | grep Nikon
> Bus 001 Device 093: ID 04b0:0428 Nikon Corp.
> ```

On Linux (and generally Unixes), 'mount' refers to attaching a filesystem to some directory ("/dev/sda2 is mounted on /boot" – the filesystem which /dev/sda2 contains was made accessible at /boot). Meanwhile USB device numbers are just numbers, assigned sequentially; this doesn't constitute 'mounting' the device.

Comment: Yes *Knut* is indeed logged in at the console. But is it impossible to find out where these things are configured? I would like to add more users to be able to access the camera.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see similar behaviour. There is a udev rule:

```
$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/50-blinkstick.rules 
# This file is installed by libbs to enable write access to BlinkStick devices
# to any seated user

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="20a0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="41e5", TAG+="uaccess", TAG+="udev-acl"

# vim: ft=udevrules
```

And indeed it uses uaccess. But if I looks at the file (/dev/bus/usb/001/003) I see normal perms and an ACL granting "me" access. If I log on via another pseudo console (ctrl-alt-Fn) and another user I see an ACL entry giving "me" (different uid) access.

so getfacl for different users on the same file returns different ACLs :

1: This seems very wrong behaviour

2: I can't see anywhere it's documented "give RW access to seat0"? Just users and groups (as always)

AFYI: The file /run/systemd/seats/seat0 features in this